# Percentage for two CGRect comparaison

Tags: ios, comparison, percentage, cgrect

How can i get percentage for comparaison for two rects?

Examples:

if r1(0, 0, 150, 150) r2(0, 0, 150, 150) so receive 100%.

if r1(0, 0, 150, 150) r2(75, 0, 150, 150) so receive 50%.

I need some function that receive two rectangles and return percentage how much there are similar..
I need the percentage of the overlapping area of the two rectangles

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I guess you can create such method.

Comment: It isn't exactly what you want, but can be useful. `BOOL isIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2); `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This;

```
var r1:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150);
var r2:CGRect = CGRect(x: 75, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150);
//--
var per = rectIntersectionInPerc(r1, r2: r2);
NSLog("per : \(per)) %");
```

-

```
//Width and Height of both rects may be different
func rectIntersectionInPerc(r1:CGRect, r2:CGRect) -> CGFloat {
    if (r1.intersects(r2)) {

       //let interRect:CGRect = r1.rectByIntersecting(r2); //OLD
       let interRect:CGRect = r1.intersection(r2);

       return ((interRect.width * interRect.height) / (((r1.width * r1.height) + (r2.width * r2.height))/2.0) * 100.0)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the rects are with different width and height?

Comment: @Rebecca see the updated function for rects of different width and height.

Comment: Thank you i will check this :-)

Comment: What is `rectByIntersecting` ?

Comment: Guess it was older Swift: Now is `intersection` I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution doesn't handle the case where one of the rectangles overlaps the other. I added this case and I refactor the API to be more idiomatic.

```swift
extension CGRect {
    func intersectionPercentage(_ otherRect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        if !intersects(otherRect) { return 0 }
        let intersectionRect = intersection(otherRect)
        if intersectionRect == self || intersectionRect == otherRect { return 100 }
        let intersectionArea = intersectionRect.width * intersectionRect.height
        let area = width * height
        let otherRectArea = otherRect.width * otherRect.height
        let sumArea = area + otherRectArea
        let sumAreaNormalized = sumArea / 2.0
        return intersectionArea / sumAreaNormalized * 100.0
    }
}
```

It's possible to use like this:

```
let percentage = frame.intersectionPercentage(otherFrame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will come in handy

```
func rectIntersectionInPerc(r1: CGRect, r2: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
   if r1.intersects(r2) {
      let interRect: CGRect = r1.intersection(r2)
      let intersectionArea = interRect.width * interRect.height
      let rectArea = r1.width * r1.height
      return (intersectionArea / rectArea) * 100.0
   }

   return 0
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the method returned the actual percentage as a float, rather than returning a number multiplied by 100.